# _Layout для определенных пользователей

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, шаблоны-проектирования, razor

После авторизации на сайта у пользователя имеется вот такое меню:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо, чтобы у **некоторых** пользователей - с логинами: `0336` `0019` `0020` появилось еще одно дополнительное меню `Мониторинг`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Наверное здесь необходимо использовать какой-то уже известный механизм или по другому сказать паттерн. Но я пытаюсь это сделать через ViewModel для _Layout:

**ViewModelBase.cs**

```
public class ViewModelBase
{
    public SchoolID { get; set; }
    public string[] monit10 = { "0336", "0019", "0020" };
}
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if(!Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {                
        return View("Index", "~/Views/Shared/_GuestLayout.cshtml");
    }
    return View(new ViewModelBase { SchoolID = User.Identity.Name });
}
```

_Layout.cshtml

```
@model Monit95App.Models.ViewModelBase
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title – приложение ASP.NET</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")    
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-2.2.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Главная", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    @if (Request.IsAuthenticated) //Если авторизация прошла успешно
                    {
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("ИТОГОВЫЕ РАБОТЫ В 1-3 КЛАССАХ", "Select", "Work201615")</li>
                    }
                    @if (Model.monit10.Contains(Model.SchoolID)) //здесь я проверяю, входит ли логин в соответствующий список
                    {
                        <li>
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Мониторинг<span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
                                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                    <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Мониторинг 10 классов</a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Общий план", "MainWindow", "Home")</li>
                                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Список обучающихся", "GetLearnesList", "Monit10_1516")</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    }                                        
                    @*<li>@Html.ActionLink("Контакты", "Contact", "Home")</li>*@ @*Контакты школы*@                 
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("О сервисе", "About", "Home")</li>                          
                </ul>

                 @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Дело в том, что все это работает после авторизации или при клики на кнопку "Главная". Если я кликну другое меню, к примеру `ИТОГОВЫЕ РАБОТЫ В 1-3 КЛАССАХ` , то на этой странице меню "Мониторинг" пропадет.

То есть как я понял, чтобы у таких пользователей постоянно было меню "Мониторинг" мне во всех методах контроллера необходимо передавать имя пользователя во View посредством:

```
 return View(new ViewModelBase { SchoolID = User.Identity.Name });
```

Как правильно сконструировать приложение для такой задачи. Ведь мне еще необходимо сделать отдельные View_шки для работы администратора (для логина администратора)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не забывайте, что `User` вам доступен в макете напрямую, не обязательно передавать его через модель!

Со списком тут, конечно, сложнее - наверное, проще всего засунуть его прямо в файл - если, конечно же, проверка происходит только в одном месте. Иначе подойдет статическое поле (я так понимаю, изменяться прямо сейчас он не должен).

```
@if (new [] { "0336", "0019", "0020" }.Contains(User.Identity.Name)) {
  ...
}
```

Наиболее аккуратным способом будет проверка роли (для этого надо сделать роль для пользователей мониторинга):

```
@if (User.IsInRole("monit10")) {
  ...
}
```